# Swipe left to go back when 1st page with UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `GetStartedViewController` which inherits from a `UINavigationController`.

This `GetStartedViewController` opens a tutorial for the app.
This tutorial is an `UIPageViewController`.

The problem is that in the `UIPageViewController` it is not possible to "swipe back" to the previous view since it already handles the swiping gestures. The only option for the user is to tap on "Back" button on the top left of the navigationBar.

Any idea of how to implement:

```
if indexScrolled == -1 {
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add a Swipe  Gesture Recognizer to your  `GetStartedViewController` ?

Assign a delegate and return false in `gestureShouldStart` if `index != 0`